# AngularJS - How to generate a random and unique numeric id and assign it to a parameter in a different scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my code, I need to generate a random and numeric id and then assign to a parameter "id" in a different scope (i.e`scope.data =  {id = "the random id"};`) but being new to Angular, I have no clue how to do this!

Comment: Well you can generate it just using plain javascript with no need of using AngularJS; have a look at this question for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: Yeah but I am pushing all the data over http (POST) to an api and a random id is a mandatory field so javascript should not be involved in this case, right? Because then If I generate a id using js, I will have to post the entire data using js and that would be pointless!

Comment: it's not really clear what you are tying to accomplish here.  what "different scope" are you talking about, and why would you think posting data to a server wouldn't involve JavaScript?  What do you mean by "If I generate a id using js, I will have to post the entire data using js"??  **Angular is JavaScript**....

Comment: this is definitely a case where a [mcve] would go a long way toward conveying what you are trying to do.

Comment: Umm the codebase I am working on involves 100% Angular and I cannot make a post request with JS because of one field, right? There must be a way to generate an id in Angular right?

Comment: Your still aren't making sense.  AngularJs is a **Framework** written in the JavaScript **Language**.  ***EVERYTHING YOU DO IN ANGULAR IS JAVASCRIPT***.  what does "I can't make a post request with JS because of one field" mean?  How else would you make a post request??

Comment: let's say, for example, you have an object `$scope.data`, and it has a bunch of properties, but needs an `id`.  why wouldn't `$scope.data.id = randomNumberFunction();` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to generate it, the best is to set your function in a service or in the $rootScope.

With this way you can call your service function or by the $rootScope.

First generate an numeric id (updated function refer to this post )

[Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

I will show you the example with the service :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('your module app name')
        .factory('guidservice', guidservice);

    guidservice.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

    function partenairesservice($rootScope) {
        var service = {
              getGuid: getGuid,
        };

        return service;

        /*
        * Return numeric unik id of 16 chr.
        */
        function getGuid() {


    function s4() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000);
      }
      return s4() + ''+ s4() + '' + s4() + '' + s4() + '' +
        s4() ;
    }
        }

    })();
```

**to use then service function in any controller scope, inject the service (guidservice)**

**and then call guidservice.getGuid();**

Comment: Can you please share an example for this? Would be really helpful, Thanks!